# Tow apparently similar JavaScript iterators give different result

Tags: javascript

The following two similar functions give me slightly different result with spread operator.

```
function take(count, iterable) {
    let index = 0;
    const iter = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
    return {
        [Symbol.iterator](){
            return this;
        },

        next: () => {
            if (count > index++) {
                 return iter.next();
            } else {
                return { done: true };
            }
        }
    };
}

function* takeGen(count, iterable) {
    let index = 0;
    const iter = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
    while(count > index++) {
        yield iter.next();
    }
}

const log = console.log;
const nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
log(...take(2, nums));
log(...takeGen(2, nums));
```

`log(...take(2, nums));` output is `1 2` 
`log(...takeGen(2, nums));` output is `{ value: 1, done: false } { value: 2, done: false }`

Why am I having two different outputs?

Answer (score 0):

In the generator function, when you `yield iter.next()`, you are returning an object representing the current state of the iterator, with the `value` and `done` properties, as the value of the current iteration.

What you actually want is the `value` of that object.

```
yield iter.next().value;
```

```js
function take(count, iterable) {
    let index = 0;
    const iter = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
    return {
        [Symbol.iterator](){
            return this;
        },

        next: () => {
            if (count > index++) {
                 return iter.next();
            } else {
                return { done: true };
            }
        }
    };
}

function* takeGen(count, iterable) {
    let index = 0;
    const iter = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
    while(count > index++) {
        yield iter.next().value;
    }
}

const log = console.log;
const nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
log(...take(2, nums));
log(...takeGen(2, nums));
```

See also: [Iteration protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)

Comment: I return iterator.next() from both functions. I think I should get the same output type { value , done }.

Comment: You are supposed to return iterator.next from the next function of the object, but yield is supposed to return the value.